# Lost all data after chkdsk on NTFS partition. How do I get it back?

Tags: ntfs, hard-drive-recovery, partition-recovery, testdisk

I have a multiboot system with a shared NTFS partition (300gigs) across OS's (Windows7, Debian, Arch).
Recently I booted into Windows and it prompted me to run CHKDSK and after that I can't see any of my data. Not only me but even testdisk fails to see any deleted files (in the Advanced>Undelete option).

I've junks and junks using Photorec but the problem is that all files are scattered across thousands of recup.* directories and are weirdly named.

In the partition there currently lies a chkdsk.log file that proudly says that it deleted 22 entries (these are the names of the directories I had in that partition).

Is there anyway I can resurrect this partition?

Comment: Not that it helps, but did you hibernate Windows before using Linux? If so, that's never a good idea.

Comment: @Karan No I didn't hibernate but my laptop ran out of battery and died abruptly.

Comment: Something very similar [just happened to me](http://superuser.com/q/745794/261779). How did this turn out for you, OP? I would sincerely appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your only option is a recovery utility such as the ones that you have used. I'd add the free Recuva from Piriform. There are also other freeware and commercial disk tools that can prove useful, but their success is not guaranteed.

All the file bytes should be there on the disk, or at least a large parte of them. Unfortunately, the file names are stored in the NTFS master file table, so, if it got corrupted, there is no way to recover them, as chkdsk actions are undoable.